# 2008 Chavy Malibu no crank no start

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, no-crank-no-start, bcm

I have 2008 Chevy Malibu that has a no crank no start it has new battery for alternator and starter tested both are good new battery post got new ignition switch still no luck I did notice that my dash message are reading traction control power steering low fuel as non of these was on there before should I replace bcm or what could it be ??? also to add I have no power going to fuel pump or throttle body ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While you said you have a new battery, did you check the charge state of the new batter at installation?